# 3D animated whiteboard drawing -- best method

Tags: grease-pencil

How can I best achieve [this effect](https://vimeo.com/291692719#t=115s) in Blender?

I'm considering:

1. White grease pencil drawing on geometry surfaces.
2. The latter with Hold Out shader (to eliminate rear strokes making them invisible)
3. Film: Transparent
4. Use Build Modifier (to get the animated drawing effect)

Thus I have to figure out tracking to moviesequences, but thats another matter

Is this the path to go or may there be more obvious methods to make the abovementioned effect in Blender?

Kind regards,
Mikael

Comment: Maybe use bezier curves to build the scene in 3d and render them as solid lines. This will give you a 3d feel because the line width will be relative to the the camera distance. I would make the scene as mesh objects and use blender's freestyle options to render them as sketched lines!

Comment: "line width will be relative to camera distance" -- a very good point :-)
"freestyle options with objects" -- also a good idea. Thus also experimenting with subdivision and Randomize-option would bring more life to basically straight mesh forms.
Thanks!

Comment: There are several freestyle options to make the lines look ‘sketchy’. This way you van keep your geometry simple and clean

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I guess that's a better solution. Yet, one question: do you know whether I can hide the "body" of the object, meaning letting the faces turn transparent AND occluding the strokes in rear -- if you understand?

Comment: Yes you can, you can render the strokes on a different layer, not painting non visible edges is an option in freestyle I believe. This way you only end up with visible drawn edges!

Comment: Cool, thanks:-)